# Installing Solaris with Window. Disk partitioning problem

Tags: installation, solaris

I am running Windows and want to install Solaris but am having hard time while using the installer.

I have 1 primary partition of 40GB and one extended partition. The extended partition has 4 logical drives. The Solaris disk management window shows only two partitions - one is of 40GB (Primary) and the second is an extended partition.

Can I convert a logical drive into a primary partition (I have one free of 25 GB)?

Please look at this screenshot of the Windows disk management utility:

[image]

Is there any way to install Solaris without reformatting and repartitioning the whole drive? If not, how should I partition and with which utility?

Answer (score 2):

Solaris doesn't support yet installing in a logical partition. It's part of the OpenSolaris caiman project: http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+caiman/Extended_Partition_Support

I don't know of a tool that can convert a logical partition to a primary one. Perhaps partition magic or gparted.

Update: Solaris 11 Express can be installed on an extended partition.